# Mapping multiple values (multipart data + json) in Post method with @RequestParam arguments

Tags: java, spring

I need to upload from Post request MultipartFile and map a class from json.
My controller code looks like this:

```
 @PostMapping(value = API_FILE_DIRECT_ENDPOINT,
            consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    FileDto create( @RequestParam("file") @NotNull MultipartFile multipartFile,
                   @PathVariable(  IbsAttachmentServiceApi.FILE_TYPE_KEY) String type,
                    @RequestParam("dto") @NotNull ApplyingFileDto applyingFileDto){
    
    FileDto result= process(applyingFileDto, multipartFile);
    
    return result;
    }
```

when I'm trying to query it from Postman, like this

[image]

but it gives me an error

```
"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.domain.ibs.attachment.model.ApplyingFileDto'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.domain.ibs.attachment.model.ApplyingFileDto': no matching editors or conversion strategy found"
```

So it doesn't map ApplyingFileDto class, only if I change it to String, and convert by ObjectMapper explicitly, then it works

```
@RequestParam("dto") @NotNull String applyingFileDto) ...
ApplyingFileDto mappedDto = objectMapper.readValue(applyingFileDto, ApplyingFileDto.class);
```

Is there is any way to configure editor to map it after @RequestParam ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for the answer. It is needed to add @RequestPart annotation instead @RequestParam like this

```
 @PostMapping(value = API_FILE_DIRECT_ENDPOINT,
            consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    FileDto create( @RequestParam("file") @NotNull MultipartFile multipartFile,
                   @PathVariable(  IbsAttachmentServiceApi.FILE_TYPE_KEY) String type,
                    @RequestPart("dto") @NotNull ApplyingFileDto applyingFileDto){
    
   FileDto result= process(applyingFileDto, multipartFile);
    
    return result;
    }
```

then reason for is in different type of converters.
[It is mentioned here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html)

> Note that @RequestParam annotation can also be used to associate the
> part of a "multipart/form-data" request with a method argument
> supporting the same method argument types. The main difference is that
> when the method argument is not a String or raw MultipartFile / Part,
> @RequestParam relies on type conversion via a registered Converter or
> PropertyEditor while RequestPart relies on HttpMessageConverters
> taking into consideration the 'Content-Type' header of the request
> part. RequestParam is likely to be used with name-value form fields
> while RequestPart is likely to be used with parts containing more
> complex content e.g. JSON, XML).

[also this example is very useful](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/samples/standalone/MultipartControllerTests.java)

Answer (score 0):

like the error says. You're trying to convert a String value to an ApplyingFileDto Object. The following method to pass objects to a service is to use the @RequestBody annotation.
I think that should solve your problem. Give it a try.

Comment: I've tired, it gives me an error 
`  "message": "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------512938824933473244238484;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "path": "/ibs-attachment/file/type/draft"`

event though, I've mentioned it 
`consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,`

Comment: That's a different problem. I see you pass a PNG file to the body but you use the '@RequestParam' annotations that will not work. You can use the '@RequestParam' annotation by setting the parameters in your url like /url?file=NotFoundQueue.PNG.

Comment: Actually it works.
this is the solution https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/samples/standalone/MultipartControllerTests.java

Answer (score 0):

It can be because you are unnecessarily including @RequestParam in the controller method. You should use @RequestBody

But before that, Make sure the attributes received as request parameters have perfect getters and setters (eg for attribute bot - setBot) on the object to be mapped.

Add the object as a parameter in the controller method, but do not annotate with @RequestParam. The setter method of the target object will be called for each matching request parameter.

Example -

```
@PostMapping()
FileDto create(@RequestBody DTO dto) {

}
```

Comment: Does it give the same error? I'm assuming you've put details in Post mapping as well. If yes, maybe you can try removing @RequestBody as well, I'll edit the answer

Comment: No, it gives an error ` "message": "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------512938824933473244238484;charset=UTF-8' not supported", "path": "/ibs-attachment/file/type/draft"` event though, I've mentioned it consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,

Comment: @ArtemEduardov I think for RequestBody,  comsumes="application/json" will work.

Comment: Deepanshu, It doesn't work because I'm sending multipart data. 
I've found solution here 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/samples/standalone/MultipartControllerTests.java

Answer (score 0):

You have `@RequestParam` but the dto was not in your params it was in the body tab